# PHP output keeps saying 'DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in'

Tags: php, arrays, dom, curl, xpath

I have this code that will retrieve every link in the `$curl_scrapped_page`:

```
require_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
$des_array = array();
$url = 'http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/search?q=mean&t=doc&sort=rlv';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page);
```

Then I want to get `abstract` for each of link (on the page of that link) I scrapped. (I also get other things like `title`, `description` and so on, but the problem only lies on this `abstract`):

```
foreach ($html->find('div.result h3 a') as $des) {
    $des2 = 'http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu' . $des->href;
    $ch = curl_init($des2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page2 = curl_exec($ch);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($curl_scraped_page2);//line 72
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $xpath2 = new DomXPath($dom);    
    $thing = $xpath2->query('//p[preceding::h3[preceding::div]]')->item(1)->textContent; //line 75   
    array_push($des_array, $thing);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

This is the display code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $des_array[$i];
}
```

When I checked it on my browser, it gave me this, thrice:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in    C:\xampp\htdocs\MSP\Citeseerx.php on line 72

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\MSP\Citeseerx.php on line 75
```

I realised I pushed an empty string to the `$des_array`. So I tried this:

```
if (empty($thing)){
    array_push($des_array,'');
}
else{
    array_push($des_array, $thing);
}
```

And this: `if ($thing!=''){..}`.

It still gave me that error.
What should I do?
Thanks..

Comment: Why don't you use `loadHTMLFile()` on the URL directly?

Comment: It won't work if the URL has `https` in it, will it?

Comment: That is normally not a problem at all, just try.

Answer (score 0):

curl_exec() may return false. In that case check with curl_error() what's the error. For example if the `href` attribute does not begin with `/` you will pass invalid url to the curl_init function. Also you may use curl_info() to get more information about the server response

Answer (score 0):

Actually the $curl_scraped_page should be an handle for an open file not a variable since you are returning the transfer as a. Binary it should be read to file you can't pass to a varible since it is not a string